# how in uibinder grid set text in specified cell

Tags: gwt, grid, uibinder

```
<g:Grid>
    <g:row>
        <g:customCell>
            <g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.loginPrompt}">
                <div>
                    <ui:msg description="LoginPrompt">Please <b>Log In</b></ui:msg> 
               </div>                       
            </g:HTMLPanel>  
        </g:customCell>         
    </g:row> 
...
```

I want that my cell text will be in second cell like in java:

```
Grid g = new Grid(5, 5);
g.setText(0, 1, "asdf");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want 5 rows and 5 columns, I think you have to define them all in the UiBinder using the appropriate number of `g:row` and `g:cell` (or `g:customCell`). There's no equivalent to `setText` but you can do the equivalent of `setHTML` by using a `g:cell` (and `g:customCell` is equivalent to `setWidget`).

```
<g:Grid>
   <g:row>
      <g:customCell><!-- whatever --></g:customCell>
      <g:cell>asdf</g:cell>
<!-- continue here for 5 rows, 5 cells per row -->
```